# How do I convert 5 V to 9 V?

Tags: voltage

I am building a guitar pedal, and I would like it to run of a 5 V rechargeable battery instead of a 9 V battery. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Thanks for reading!

Comment: Where are you finding a 5V rechargeable battery from? I know of no cell chemistry that gives you 5V. In any case, buy a boost or step-up switching converter module and use that.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/aimtec/AMSRI-7805-NZ/12440114 but you'll probably want to use a 6.5V then use a voltage regulator to clean up the switching noise

Comment: "Spare power boxes" or "power banks" with USB connector are commonly available. As well one can buy an USB to 9VDC converter and avoid messing with own constructions. One example: https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GD54Q66 But I guess the actual idea of the question was "how to in a general way convert the schematic of a 9V pedal to an equivalent sounding one which needs only 5VDC and how to do it directly as native 5V circuit - not by boosting 5V to 9V?"

Answer (score 3):

You need a thing called a "boost converter".  If you were a product designer you'd probably design one onto your board, but that's a job for the experienced -- if you need to ask, it's probably beyond you.

You can get cheap unreliable ones from eBay or hobby electronics sources, or you can get reliable ones from distributors.  Basically, if it doesn't have a full data sheet, and you don't have a route to send a defective part back to the vendor, don't trust it.

Careful shopping is in order.

Comment: Don't buy stuff without datasheets. You might as well be buying canned food without labels on the tin or mystery boxes.

Comment: @DKNguyen: It's too bad I can't give you +10 on that instead of just +1.  I'm about to edit your comment into my answer.

Comment: ... or buying a problem with no idea of what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're operating from something like a power bank, and consumption is less than a few hundred mA, you can use one of the inexpensive modules based on the Xian Aerosemi [MT3608](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811151539_XI-AN-Aerosemi-Tech-MT3608_C84817.pdf).

They generally have this schematic (from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/535125/alternate-inductor-that-can-be-used-for-mt3608-boost-converter-circuit) question:

[image]

Adjust the pot to set the output voltage to +9V before connecting it to the other circuitry, of course.

You can either wire the 5V to the PCB terminals **or** use a USB cable and plug it into your power bank.

The MT3608 operates at 1.2MHz so it requires only a tiny 22uH inductor, but the downside is that it is not breadboard-friendly as a component. As a module there are fewer worries.

Answer (score 0):

Two 5V batteries can be recharged as OP requires when wired in parallel. Add a switch to place them in series once recharged, for 10V to operate your pedal. If 10V is too high, use a diode or two to drop the voltage.